# java reading from Socket hangs

Tags: java, sockets

I have to implement a communication between terminal and a POS terminal over TCP/IP. What I have is IP and port of pos terminal and protocol specification.

In java I have done a simple example to write to a socket, but my app freeze when I want to read from a socket (until timeout is reached)..

What I'am doing wrong?

```
 try {
        pos = new Socket("172.16.201.217", 1500);
        pos.setSoTimeout(5000);

        output = new DataOutputStream(pos.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("is connected?:" + pos.isConnected());
        String amount = "100";
        String p = "000000123401100" + FS + amount + FS + FS + "+0" + FS + "705" + FS + FS + FS + FS + FS + FS + FS + ETX;

        //Podatki is a method which adds some additional chars + CRC.. 
        byte[] protokol = Podatki(p);

        //here I send a complete array of bytes to my pos...
        output.write(protokol, 0, protokol.length);
        output.flush();

        Thread.sleep(1000);


        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pos.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        String response = "";
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            response = response + line + "\n";
            if (input.ready() == false) {
                break;
            }
```

what I get is timeout exception..
What I expect is a response from pos terminal which can be  ACK (acknowledge) or NAK (negative acknowledge).

thank you.

Comment: try opening the inputstream before the outputstream

Comment: You have written some thing on socket. When you open InputStream on socket, some one else have to write data on other end.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your message is *not finished* (may be it is waiting for a particular end of message character or sequence of characters for example) so the POS is waiting for the rest of the message. In this situation the timeout on your code comes before an error message of pos.

To check it use a socket sniffer between your code and the POS so you can see what exactly is passing between client and server and viceversa.

Comment: I tryed to replace pos terminal IP with google.com ip and port 80.. in this case I get response from the "other" side..  I think the problem is in pos terminal which not send back any relevant data..  (it hangs on getInputStream)... I will contact POS terminal support ;)

Comment: Search for a sniffer there are many open source or free to use. Probably you have to add some final char to your request. Sometimes a request is closed with a couple of new line as for example for standard HTTP requests.

Comment: The pos terminal sucessfully recognized the "stream" which I send over socket.. but I can't get response from pos.. I don't know what else to do.. or what other "sign"  to send ..  From the support I have received a .net version of compiled program which sends stream over socket to pos terminal but in this case the pos terminal send back ACK sign... From the "monitor" in this program I can read what are the input and output stream charaters.. There is no special sign which program send to pos terminal...

Comment: Solved... the problem was that I have never closed the inputStream.. (When I run the programm for the first time I get response back from socket)..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be reading lines but not writing lines. `readLine()` will block until end of stream or an exception or a line terminator is encountered. If you don't send a line terminator and don't close the socket and no network errors occur, `readLine()` at the peer will block forever.

Send a line terminator: `\n` or `\r\n`.